# Linking two hashmaps via searching or is there a better way?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hashmap for orders and another one for orderitems. A method which puts the data into the hashmaps is executed like this:

```
    // THIS ONE ADDS THE ORDERS
    // (int orderNumber, String Datum, String salesperson, int customernumber)
    mainController.addBestallning(500, "2012/01/01", "Hendrik Gustafsson", 1001);

    // THIS ONE ADDS THE ORDERED ITEMS
    // (int orderNumber, int linePos, Artikel product, int amount, double price)
    mainController.addBestallningsOrderRad(500, 1, mainController.getAllaArtiklar().get(101), 5, 100.00);
```

Once I find an order by its ordernumber, how do I find the ordereditems?
The only link I have now is the ordernumber, which I save in orderitemshashmap, so I assume some sort of iteration needs to take place, find the matches and return the results.

I tried doing this and got it to work, but only under condition that all of the orderitem positions are also unique.

So, if I was to add another order like this:

```
mainController.addBestallning(501, "2011/05/02", "Sven Karmageddon", 1002);            
mainController.addBestallningsOrderRad(501, 1, mainController.getAllaArtiklar().get(101), 5, 100.00);
```

I could not find the orderitems for order 501.

Here is what I tried so far. Made a method to find all orders of a customer:

```
public HashMap<Integer, Bestallning> getAllaKundOrdrar() {
    HashMap<Integer, Bestallning> allaKundOrderHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    //iterate through all orders
    //find the ones which belong to customerid
    //place them in allaKundOrderHashMap
    //return allaKundOrderHashMap
Iterator iter = tmpBestallningsregister.getAllaBestallningar().keySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Integer key = (Integer) iter.next();
    //String value = (String) controller.getAllaKunder().get(key).getKundNamn();              
    if ((customerNrToFindOrdersFor) == getAllaBestallningar().get(key).getKundNr()) {
        //found an order for this customer, putting it in the hashmap                
        allaKundOrderHashMap.put(key, getAllaBestallningar().get(key));
    }
}
return allaKundOrderHashMap;
}
```

A method to find all ordereditems from all customers (100% wrong to search like this, I know) and get the ones beloning to a specific order:

```
    //RETURN OF ORDERRADERS HASHMAP FOR SPECIFIC ORDER VIA ORDERREGISTER
public HashMap<Integer, BestallningsOrderRad> getAllaBestallningsBestallningsOrderRader() {
    HashMap<Integer, BestallningsOrderRad> allaBestallningsOrderRaderHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    //iterate through all orderrader
    //find the ones which belong to orderid
    //place them in allaKundOrderRaderHashMap
    //return allaKundOrderRaderHashMap                       

    Iterator iter = tmpBestallningsregister.getAllaBestallningsOrderRader().keySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Integer key = (Integer) iter.next();         

        if ((orderNrToFindOrderRaderFor) == tmpBestallningsregister.getAllaBestallningsOrderRader().get(key).getBestallningsNr()) {                
            //found an orderrad for this order, putting it in the hashmap
            //allaBestallningsOrderRaderHashMap.put(key, getAllaBestallningsOrderRader().get(key));
            allaBestallningsOrderRaderHashMap.put(key, getAllaBestallningsOrderRader().get(key));                
        }
    }
    return allaBestallningsOrderRaderHashMap;
}
```

Anyone care to tell me what is it that I am doing wrong?
I've been at this for 20 hours straight...

Comment: "...this is pure hell". Congratulations, you are a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use two different `Map`, but only one. What you need is to properly define a `Order` class that holds all the order data (including suborders, which are sheldom used outside the order) and use just a `Map<Integer,Order>`

If you insist in having two separate Maps, the second uses the same id but stores a `List` (it looks like you want it ordered) of suborders.

```
private Map<Integer, Order> orders;
private Map<Integer, List<SubOrder> suborders;
```

Stopping a moment before beginning to code and thinking the more appropiate data structures will usually save you a lot of "hell" later.

Comment: We are forced to use a separate class which holds information about ordered items and amount ordered.

Comment: How exactly would you define the order class so that it can keep multiple ordered products? I can think of an attribute type String where you could set the ordered item partnumber, but one instance of an order can only store 1 such item.

Comment: A `java.util.List` is always ordered.